# ForEach-Object/Copy-Item only content (not the folder itself!)

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I have code that looks for folders and afterwards it looks for the criteria I am telling it. So far so good. Then I got a `ForEach-Object` with a `Copy-Item $_.Fullname` in it. The code itself is working and spitting no errors, but I don't want to copy the folder itself + its content. I just want to copy the content of the folder. I already tried things like `$_.Fullname/*` and so on.

Here's how my code looks like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $DestinationBackup | Where {
    $_.Name -like "$BackupName_Differential3*"
} | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Destination $Differential_Destination -Force
}
```

**Edit 1:**

My Folder structure looks like this:

```
M143                       ← (Root Folder)
├─Backups                  ← (Folder, here are Backups stored)
│ ├─Fullbackup...
│ ├─Incrementalbackup...   ← Copy Content of this folder, without folder)
│ └─Differentialbackup...  ← (Into this folder)
└─Backup_Script.ps1
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path "$DestinationBackup\*" | ...`?

Comment: I tried your answer (With "/" and with " \"), but it's still doing the same as before.

Comment: Please show a sample of your directory structure and indicate what exactly you want copied.

Comment: Do you have multiple incremental backup folders or just one? Does your source folder contain only files or subfolders as well? Also, why would you want to copy incremental backups to a folder for differential backups in the first place?

Comment: I got a folder called "incremental backup". in this folders are for every incremental backup folders like "[Backupname]-Incremental-Date-Time". My Source Folder only contains files at the moment, but it should also work with subfolders. I am copying incremental backups to a folder for differential backups, because I am testing an "alternate" way for differential backup. (No RoboCopy, not allowed to use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ...

```
Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse
```

... is your issue. The below should be what you wanted.

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path E:\BackUps -Recurse).FullName
```

Results before Copy

```
E:\BackUps\Differential
E:\BackUps\Full
E:\BackUps\Incremental
E:\BackUps\Incremental\IncBU001.bkp
E:\BackUps\Incremental\IncBU002.bkp
E:\BackUps\Incremental\IncBU003.bkp

Copy-Item -Path 'E:\BackUps\Incremental\*' -Destination 'E:\BackUps\Differential'

(Get-ChildItem -Path E:\BackUps -Recurse).FullName
```

Results after copy

```
E:\BackUps\Differential
E:\BackUps\Full
E:\BackUps\Incremental
E:\BackUps\Differential\IncBU001.bkp
E:\BackUps\Differential\IncBU002.bkp
E:\BackUps\Differential\IncBU003.bkp
E:\BackUps\Incremental\IncBU001.bkp
E:\BackUps\Incremental\IncBU002.bkp
E:\BackUps\Incremental\IncBU003.bkp
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that might do the trick. I just don't seem to implement it correct in my code. My code looks at the moment like this: `$SearchBackup = (Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Backups -Recurse).FullName
$SearchBackup  | Where {$SearchBackup -like "$BackupName_Differential3*" | ForEach-Object  {
    Copy-Item -Path 'E.\Backups\Incremental\*' -Destination 
    'E:\Backups\Differential'
}`

Comment: Thank you so much! I realised my mistake.
Your Solution was: `Copy-Item -Path 'I:\TBZ\M143\Backups\IncrementalBackup\*' -recurse -Destination $Differential_Destination -Force`
I wrote the following and now it works: `Copy-Item -Path 'I:\TBZ\M143\Backups\IncrementalBackup\*\*' -recurse -Destination $Differential_Destination -Force`

So I just had to add an extra **\asterik**